# Google or other maps- tracking whether inside or outside a building

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I'm wondering whether it would be possible to track if a person is inside a building or outside using some available sdk's,
Of course very aproximately speaking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it only needs to be approximately, check to see if they can get a high accuracy location from the GPS. When in buildings often the GPS won't get a signal with a satellite.